# Switch tabs via mouse scroll

Tags: xfce4-terminal

Is it possible to switch tabs in xfce4-terminal via scrolling the mouse wheel? Like, for example, scrolling up is equivalent to ctrl + pageUp.

What I mean exactly: I would like to move my cursor on a tab and then, while scrolling on the mouse wheel, the current tab is switching.

Edit:
lxterminal offers this feature out of the box. Unfortunately it seems deprecated / does not offer as many features as xfce4-terminal.

Comment: Just hover your mouse pointer on the tabs bar.

Comment: KDE's Konsole supports this when you move the mouse pointer to the tab bar and press Ctrl while scrolling; if that doesn't work for you, you could also try pressing Shift or Alt.